# Update a term date column based on the next record effective date

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help me on this?I have data in a table as below

**Input**:

```
IDNO  EFFECTIVE DATE       TERM DATE
-------------------------------------    
100   10/01/2001           12/01/2012           
100   03/12/2013           05/02/2013           
100   05/03/2013           01/04/2014                  
100   10/10/2014           12/31/9999 
200   01/01/2017           02/15/2017
200   03/01/2017           12/31/2017
```

And the desired output:

```
IDNO  EFFECTIVE DATE       TERM DATE
-------------------------------------
100   10/01/2001           03/11/2012           
100   03/12/2013           05/02/2013           
100   05/03/2013           10/09/2014                  
100   10/10/2014           12/31/9999 
200   01/01/2017           02/28/2017
200   03/01/2017           12/31/9999
```

Term date should be one day prior to the effective day and the latest record term date should always be  `12/31/9999`

I may have N number of records for the same id.

Specified the date values in `MM/DD/YY`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lead(effective_date) over (partition by idno order by effective_date) as next_effective_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set term_date = coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, next_effective_date), '9999-12-31')
    where term_date <> coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, next_effective_date), '9999-12-31');
```

Comment: What if you remove the where cluase? will the update run faster or slower? The results are going to be the same anyway...

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I believe that SQL Server would update all rows, even if the values do not change.  That incurs additional overhead for logging.

Comment: Yes, but the filtering of the rows also takes time. I've seen select statements running faster when the where clause was removed, was wondering if that might be the same for updates.